Hibernate does not release the table lock when the transaction ends
There is a service that manages the queue: it selects a client for an operator and records them both in the database.
public class ClientService {

    @Transactional
    public ClientDTO method1(Long userId) {
        //some code
        return method2(userId);
    }
    
    @Transactional
    public ClientDTO method2(Long userId) {
        //some code
        ClientDTO client = anotherClass.getClient();
        return method3(userId, ClientDTO.getId());
    }
    
    @Transactional
    public ClientDTO method3(Long userId, Long clientId) {
        User user = userRepository.findByIdForUpdate(userId).get();
        Client client = clientRepository.findByIdForUpdate(clientId).get();
        client.setUser(user);
        client.setStatus(Constants.CLIENT_STATUS_CALLED));
        user.setStatus(Constants.OPERATOR_STATUS_WAITING_FOR_THE_CALLED_CLIENT);
        result = mapper.toDTO(client);
        //some code
        return result;
    }   
}

The problem is that this algorithm is overcomplicated and takes too long to execute. And the service is running in a cluster: there are several service instances that execute this code in parallel. Races began: one client was assigned to different operators or one operator was assigned different clients.
It was decided to introduce locks at the DB level. It was also decided to move the piece of code that sets the statuses for the client and the operator to a separate transaction method: so that this operation would be executed as atomically as possible.
public interface UserRepository extends GenericRepository<User> {
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    Optional<User> findByIdForUpdate(Long id);
}

public interface ClientRepository extends GenericRepository<Client> {
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)
    Optional<Client> findByIdForUpdate(Long id);
}

public class ClientService {

    //@Transactional
    public ClientDTO method1(Long userId) {
        //some code
        return method2(userId);
    }
    
    //@Transactional
    public ClientDTO method2(Long userId) {
        //some code
        final short tryCount = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < tryCount; i++) {
            ClientDTO client = anotherClass.getClient();
            try {
                result = method3(userId, ClientDTO.getId());
            } catch (ClientIsBusyException e) {
                log.info("try again");
                continue;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    
    //@Transactional
    public ClientDTO method3(Long userId, Long clientId) throws ClientIsBusyException {
        result = clientTransactionalService.clientSetStateCalled(userId, clientId);
        //some code
        return result;
    }   
}

public class ClientTransactionalService {
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public ClientDTO clientSetStateCalled(Long userId, Long clientId) throws ClientIsBusyException {
        User user = userRepository.findByIdForUpdate(userId).get();
        if(Constants.OPERATOR_STATUS_WAITING_FOR_THE_CALLED_CLIENT.equals(user.getStatus().getId())
            throw new IllegalStateException();
            
        Client client = clientRepository.findByIdForUpdate(clientId).get();
        if (client.getUser() != null && !Objects.equals(client.getUser().getId(), userId))
            throw new ClientIsBusyException();
            
        client.setUser(user);
        client.setStatus(Constants.CLIENT_STATUS_CALLED));
        user.setStatus(Constants.OPERATOR_STATUS_WAITING_FOR_THE_CALLED_CLIENT);
        return mapper.toDTO(client);
    }
}

But this led to other problems. Now there is a bunch of code that is not included in the REQUIRES_NEW transaction. I don't know in which transaction it is executed.
Now in some scenarios, when method1 is called twice in a row, the first time it locks the record in the Client table, but does not release the lock at the end of the clientSetStateCalled method. On the second call, clientRepository.findByIdForUpdate hangs, waiting for the lock to expire.
I have two questions:

How does Hibernate manage transactions if @Transactional is not set?
How can I ensure that the lock on the tables is 100% released with the clientSetStateCalled method?

